# Given an isosceles right-triangle $\triangle ABC$ with 3 squares on the hypotenuse, find the area of the largest square.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, triangles

As the title suggests, the question is to solve for the area of the largest square in the following figure given the area of 2 smaller ones. This is a pretty fun problem and I want to see if there are any more ways to solve it, such as with trigonometry. As always, I'll post my own approach as an answer below!
[image: ni]

Comment: Isn't there not enough information.  After all angle of the isoceles triangle can be anything between $45$ to $180$ degrees and the smaller the angle the smaller the small rectangles and the larger the angle the larger the small squares.

Comment: It says "isosceles right-triangle", that significantly narrows it down to just one option @fleablood

Comment: Ah... well in that case we have the angles are $22.5$ and the problem ought to be simple trig.  All three sides add to $2 \sin 45$ and the big square side is $2\sin 22.5$  So the small square side is $\sin 45 - \sin 22.5$ and the area of the big circle compared the are of the two smaller squares is $\frac{4\sin^2 22.5}{2(\sin 45-\sin 22.5)}$.

Comment: @fleablood I don't think we're on the same page here. It is geometrically impossible for there to be an angle of measure 22.5° in this particular configuration

Comment: ????? Of course there is!  $\frac {90 - 45}2 = 22.5=\frac {45}2$.  You have a $45$ degree isoceles triangle inside a $90$ degree triangle.  So those two smaller angles must be $22.5$  Unless the two small squares are not congruent.

Comment: @fleablood $\triangle EBF$ is not isosceles, $\triangle ABC$ is (refer to my figure below). Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Okay, even if the squares are not congruent we have $\sin(\alpha + \beta + 45)= \sin 90$ and we can set up the trig.

Comment: "Please read the question carefully."  Please *write* the question carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The large square's area is always the sum of the other two squares' areas.

[image]

Say $\triangle ABC$ is our isosceles right triangle, with right angle at $A$. $D$ and $E$ are on hypotenuse $BC$, and $\angle DAE$ measures $45^\circ$. Reflect $C$ across line $AD$ to find point $F$ — that is, $\angle CAD = \angle DAF$ and $AC=AF$. Then

$$ 90^\circ = \angle CAB = \angle CAD + \angle DAE + \angle EAB = \angle CAD + \angle EAB + 45^\circ $$
$$ 45^\circ = \angle CAD + \angle EAB $$
$$ 45^\circ = \angle DAE = \angle DAF + \angle FAE $$

Since by construction $\angle CAD = \angle DAF$, this gives $\angle EAB = \angle FAE$. We then have (SAS) two congruent triangle pairs, $\triangle ACD \cong \triangle AFD$ and $\triangle ABE \cong \triangle AFE$.

The congruences give $\angle DFA = \angle DCA = 45^\circ$ and $\angle AFE = \angle ABE = 45^\circ$, so $\angle DFE = \angle DFA + \angle AFE = 90^\circ$, and $\triangle DEF$ is a right triangle. By the Pythagorean theorem, $DF^2+EF^2=DE^2$. By the congruent triangles again, $CD=DF$ and $BE=EF$. Finally,

$$ CD^2+BE^2=DE^2 $$

Comment: Excellent approach!

Comment: The most insightful one imo.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Here is an alternative approach that leads to the same conclusion as that of aschepler.

Rotate $\Delta BAE$   $  90^o$ about $B$ to obtain $\Delta BCF$ as shown.

Note that

(1) $AE=CF$

(2) $\Delta BDE \cong \Delta BDF $ (SAS)$\implies DE=DF$

(3) $\angle DCF=90^o$

From Pythagoras Theorem,
$CF^2+CD^2=DF^2$

Hence  $AE^2+CD^2=DE^2$

Answer (score 2):

According to the Goku's figure, let $AB=BC=m$, $AE=a$, $EF=z$, $FC=b$. By Law of sines, in $\triangle ABE$ we have $\frac{a}{\sin\alpha}=\frac{m}{\sin(135-\alpha)}$ and in $\triangle BFC$ we have $\frac{b}{\sin(45-\alpha)}=\frac{m}{\sin(90+\alpha)}$. By eliminating $m$ we get $\tan(2\alpha)=\frac{a}{b}.$

Here, $a=2$, $b=2\sqrt{3}$, so $\alpha=15$.

By law of sines in $\triangle BFC$, $\frac{b}{\sin30}=\frac{BF}{\sin45}$ and thus $BF=2\sqrt{6}$.

By law of sines in $\triangle ABF$, we have $\frac{BF}{\sin45}=\frac{z+a}{\sin60}$ and $z+2=6$ and thus $z=EF=4$. So the area of the big square is $4^2=16$.

Comment: Nice approach by finding the angle $\alpha$ first. +1

Answer (score 1):

This is my method of solving it. I'll explain below:

[image]

Here's my explanation:

1.) Label the triangle as $\triangle ABC$ with two points $E$ and $F$ on the hypotenuse. Notice that since $\angle FBE=45$, we can set $\angle FBC=\alpha$ and that means that $\angle EBA=45-\alpha$. In other words $\angle FBC+\angle EBA=45$. Using this fact, we can rotate $\triangle BFC$ BG $90$ counterclockwise to form a new triangle $\triangle BDA$ outside of $\triangle ABC$ which will be congruent to $\triangle BFC$

2.) This means that $BD=BF$ and that $\angle DBA=45-\alpha$. However, this implies that $\angle DBE=45$, therefore, we can say that $\triangle DBE$ is congruent to $\triangle EBF$. By joining $D$ and $E$ via $DE$, we can say that $DE=EF$ as well. Now, since the areas of the given squares are $4$ and $12$ respectively, their side lengths would be $2$ and $2\sqrt{3}$ respectively, as well. Which means that $DA=2\sqrt{3}$ and $AE=2$. Notice that since $\angle DAB=45$ and $\angle BAC=45$, we know that $\angle DAE=90$. This means that $\triangle DAE$ is a right-angle triangle with sides $2$ and $2\sqrt{3}$, and thus, by applying the Pythagorean theorem we have:

$$DE^2=(2)^2+(2\sqrt{3})^2=16$$

This means that $DE^2=EF^2=16$, which gives us the answer that the area of the largest square is $16$.